# How/where can I ask to support an audio chip?

Tags: drivers, audio

I've been a Ubuntu / Mint / POP OS user for about 20 years, and now I'm forced to use Windows because my audio chip is not working on Linux.

I've done a probe (https://linux-hardware.org/?id=pci:8086-3198-2782-0204) and the chip is detected but not working on major distributions.

I've got 2 questions:

1. is there any hope to see this chip supported in the near future? (let's say one year)
2. how does it work? who chooses which devices to support? is there a place where I can ask Linux developers to develop drivers for that device? or some crowdfunding... I really want to support this, but don't know where to start.

Sorry for the dumb questions. I don't really know how things work, I mean, by the human organization point of view, who is in charge of taking these decisions. All these years when I had a problem I was researching on the web, then trying to solve problems, but this one is beyond my knowledge.

Comment: Don't tell us her that you have been using Linux for 20 years without your Intel HDAudio working ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> is there any hope to see this chip supported in the near future? (let's say one year)

The chip is fully supported since at least kernel 4.11 (as the website you link to shows! "Detected" doesn't mean "does not work"). Linux 4.11 is more than 5 years old – so, *every* major Linux distro does in fact support your chip!

So, yes, it will still be supported – now, and most likely also in a year :D

So, your other question is a bit "over the top": There's no reason to assume you cannot use it for lack of linux support.

> how does it work? who chooses which devices to support?

Whoever sits down and writes the Linux kernel driver, and brings it into a shape that the Linux kernel subsystem maintainer says "OK, this code is good and reliable enough to be included in Linux". So, two parties: the person (or persons) writing the driver, and the maintainer (or maintainers) of the operating system kernel that accepts (or does not accept) the resulting driver into the Linux kernel.

<sup>(Usually, maintainers strive to support as many devices as possible, but that doesn't mean at any cost; the code they accept immediately becomes their burden to carry on through kernel updates forever. The quality of code really matters – it's great if your operating system supports every sound card and webcam under the sky, but not so great if it crashes every 24 seconds because some C developers wouldn't find the exit in an igloo programmatically without starting a house fire in the process.)</sup>

Generally, intel and AMD do make sure that the hardware in their chipsets is supported under Linux at the point they introduce it to the market; big hardware purchasers put their money where the software support is, so especially intel pays a small army of kernel developers to make sure their stuff just works – especially since they literally won't be selling enough server CPUs to even offset development costs if they're not supported by the Linux kernel; and desktop hardware tends to benefit from existing drivers as well.

> is there a place where I can ask Linux developers to develop drivers for that device?

There's freelancing developers who can write drivers for money, and larger consulting businesses. But in both cases, we'd be talking much much more money than a laptop's or PC's worth here; driver developers that know how to write drivers that are good enough for upstream Linux are kind of in demand by companies building hardware ;)

**But**, the problem you're having with your audio doesn't stem from the fact that the PCI audio device is not supported by your Linux. There might be a myriad of other things wrong – from the default configuration of the device not fitting the realities of the connections on the board, over misconfigured audio systems to strange driver interactions.

But so far, what you report doesn't indicate anything about this is a problem that can be solved with money; first thing I'd honestly do is open a different question here that says

> I have {this and that} hardware; although it seems supported by the kernel, I can get {precise description of what does and doesn't work}. I've tried {description of what you've tried}, and I'm out of ideas. What do I investigate next to enable me to {what you want to do}?

Comment: SE should create a special gold badge for anyone taking care of writing a more than 1 line and a half answer to that sort of question ;-) my modest +1 to compensate !

Comment: @MC68020 thank you!

Comment: Thank you so much @MarcusMüller for being supportive and sharing with me things I didn't know. I really appreciate people who spend time and energy to help others!